# No response from any API routes when using Serverless-offline plugin

Tags: python-3.x, serverless-offline, fastapi

```py
from mangum import Mangum
from fastapi import FastAPI


app = FastAPI()


@app.post("/items/")
def create_item(item_id: int):
    return {"id": item_id}


@app.get("/items/")
def list_items():
    items = [{"id": i} for i in range(10)]
    return items


@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World!"}


handler = Mangum(app)
```

I'm using the above code when specified in `main.py` and it's configured with a catch-all route in `serverless.yml`. I want to test it locally using the `serverless-offline` plugin but when I run the offline plugin using `sls offline`, I don't get any response in the browser for any routes. It just says, `localhost didn’t send any data`.

What could I be doing wrong? The offline plugin is listening on port `3000` by default.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that I hadn't exposed port 3000 from my Docker image. Doing that immediately solved my problem.